# Awkward OOP: Same method on different classes not inherited?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Here's the deal:
I have two objects of different classes, a `DataSizeAction` and a `DataColorAction`. The classes have a common ancestor `EncoderAction` not far up the chain.

Both these objects expose a method called `setScale(int scale)` which sets a scale type for the encoding they carry out. The method does the same thing in both cases.

However, the method is not present in any common ancestor (btw, this OO is a Library I'm using and the design is not up to my discretion).

I would like to write a method that takes either a DataSizeAction or DataColorAction and calls setScale on that object.

My question is: before I go brute-forcing the separate cases with `instanceof`, is there a more elegant way to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you add interfaces to your hierarchy?

```
interface IScalable {
   void setScale(int scale);
   int getScale();
}

class DataSizeAction extends EncoderAction implements IScalable {
   ...
}

class SomeoneElse {
   private int scale = 2;

   public void setScale(IScalable scalable) {
      scalable.setScale(this.scale);
   }
}
```

Comment: Aight, that should work, although because DataSizeAction and DataColorAction are both library classes (sorry I didn't clarify that), I'll have to extend both and implement the new interface in the subclasses.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. Make another class which extends `EncoderAction`
2. Declare `setScale` as an abstract method within there
3. Have `DataSizeAction` and `DataColorAction` extend your new class.

Now, you can write your code to refer to instances of the new base class and avoid calling `instanceof` checks.

**NOTE**:  Even though what I have here should work, I would recommend [Jonathon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203600/jonathon)'s answer.  Since this is a gaurantee of functionality and doesn't have anything to do with your object's composition, interfaces are likely the way to go.

Comment: you should note that he mentioned its a library in which he cant do this modification

Comment: Actually, see Jonathon's answer.  I think that is better.

Comment: as you say, an interface is preferable for this approach, but good thinking!