# How to call same method from two different classes in java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have two classes **Apple** and **Orange** like this:

```
public final  class Apple{
    int getJuice();
}
public final class Orange{
    int getJuice();
}
```

**and I cannot change them**.
I have third class **fruitsManeger** like this:

```
class FruitManeger {
     Apple apple;
     Orange orange;

     enum Fruits{
        Apple,Orange
     }

     Fruits favorFruits;    

     int getJoice(){
         if(favorFruits==Fruits.Apple){
               apple.getJuice();
         }else if(favorFruits==Fruits.Orange){
               orange.getJuice();
         } 
     }

}
```

My Question: what is best way to implement getJuice method in **FruitManeger** class?.

as you can see if I have a lot of fruits I should add a lot of **if else** expiration.

of course, I can use reflection to call methods by name but it's not a good idea when getJuice method return an object and you want to do something same with that.

is there any better way?

Comment: i cannot change apple and orange class

Comment: We will just have to ask why you cannot change Apple and Orange... because the huge amount of if/case statements you'd need is a direct result of that. By the way you can use Reflection to handle the returned object as well.... you'd just need more if/case statements.

Comment: because Apple and orange is in java library

Comment: Apple and Orange are non final classes, extend those then... look my suggested answer please...

Comment: I think you should read about factory design pattern.It is perfect scenario for your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> *is there any better way?*

Yes, Refactor that application into a more oop way...

**Remember: you cannot Modify Apple or Orange, but OOP allows you extending those classes for sure since they are not final...**

```
class CorrectApple extends Apple implement IJuiceble{
    @Override
    int getJuice();
}
class CorrectOrange extends Orange  implement IJuiceble{
    @Override
    int getJuice();
}
```

now the

```
interface IJuiceble{
    int getJuice();
}
```

and finally the manager:

```
class FruitManeger {
     private CorrectApple apple;
     private CorrectOrange orange;

     int getJoice(IJuiceble correctfruit){
         return correctfruit.getJuice();
     }
}
```

Comment: a moving target

Comment: @max well if you dont provide the correct/complete information then this answer is not even going to compile... and my design is now useless....

Comment: You could still make a CorrectApple that has an Apple.

Comment: Can we achieve same thing using annotations? That would save redefining all classes?

Comment: Question: Should FruitManager also implement IJuicable as a good practice? Should the class FruitManager be called FruitFactory as a good practice? Should we have a List storing all the fruits in FruitManager so we can easily loop through the fruits?

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch instead of if/else.

```
class FruitManager {
    Apple apple;
    Orange orange;

    enum Fruits {
        Apple, Orange
    }

    Fruits favorFruits;

    int getJoice() {
        switch (favorFruits) {
        case Apple:
            apple.getJuice();
            break;
        case Orange:
            orange.getJuice();
            break;

        default:
            System.err.println("Fruit not found. " + favorFruits);
        }
    }
```

Comment: the more fruits you have in the manager the bigger the switch case and the enum....

Comment: It's a bad solution, but is a solution for the question. I prefer the interface solution as well.

Comment: I like the way you approached anyway\

Answer (score -1):

By referring this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907711/awkward-oop-same-method-on-different-classes-not-inherited)

```
interface IScalable {
   void setScale(int scale);
   int getScale();
}

class DataSizeAction extends EncoderAction implements IScalable {
   ...
}

class SomeoneElse {
   private int scale = 2;

   public void setScale(IScalable scalable) {
      scalable.setScale(this.scale);
   }
}
```

Comment: The question stated, for whatever reason, the classes Apple and Orange cannot be changed, and they don't implement or extend anything.